# Stepper behavior in an NSDatePicker messed up?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdate, nsdatepicker

I have an `NSDatePicker` with text and stepper. The steppers show behavior that I find quite unintuitive. If my date picker is at the 26th of April and I select the day number, then click "up" a few times, the date picker cycles *back* to April 1st after the 30th!

[image]

How do I make the picker continue into May?

Comment: What happens if you select the month, and then click up a few times?

Comment: It goes up to 12, then back to 1. Same year!

Comment: And what happens if you select the year, and then click up a few times?

Comment: It keeps going up. Nothing strange there.

Comment: This kind of behavior is not exactly unprecedented; it's much simpler to set a date (or a time on a clock, etc.) this way, rather than having to cycle through endless numbers of days (or minutes) to get to where you want, and it would be counter-intuitive to have it work both ways.

Comment: That is true, but if my user would want to add 7 days, it's quite a bit more work. I would expect some way to select the stepper behavior, but I do not think there's a one-line way to do it.

Comment: Does Cocoa offer a dropdown calendar object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use the delegate method `- (void)datePickerCell:(NSDatePickerCell *)aDatePickerCell validateProposedDateValue:(NSDate **)proposedDateValue timeInterval:(NSTimeInterval *)proposedTimeInterval` as it sends a message whenever the date changes, however it does not inform whether the change was made through the buttons or through keyboard, so if the user manually changed the date from `30-04-2013` to `01-04-2013` you have no way of telling if they did it with the buttons or with the keyboard. You might be able to subclass the buttons to detect if a click happened, but I would say that's too much of a hassle. I would say this should be the least of your worries, or you could do what Robert Harvey suggested which is to use a dropdown calendar, which can be changed using the method `[datePicker setDatePickerStyle:NSClockAndCalendarDatePickerStyle]` or through interface builder.